# Parallel Dacpac deployment - Disable dependencies?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

In my company we are working on doing CI and CD and using SqlPackage to deploy dacpacs.

due to the fact the each Dacpac takes a while we are running them in parallel. yet sometimes we are encountering issues in regards to dependencies - e.g: DB A is being deployed but depends on DB B which is also being deployed at the same time (for example a stored procedure dependency)

is there any way to run the sqlpackage with some flag or something to ignore these dependencies and not fail when deploying?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous deployment of this type is not the recommended approach. But I suppose you could write a [deployment contributor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn306642(v=vs.103).aspx) that finds steps that require an external dependency and rewrite the step's TSQL such that it will retry the TSQL until it succeeds or surpasses a set limit on execution time or retry count. Note that this could produce a deadlock in the case of circular dependencies, so hopefully you have none.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting "Invalid object name 'XX.XX.XX'" or something similar?

This is a sql requirement, when you do a create/alter sql compiles it and validates that it is correct so if the dependencies haven't been deployed yet sql won't let you deploy the updates.

You will need to deploy them in the correct order I am afraid.

To limit the actual deploy time (but won't stop the overall time) you could generate the scripts and then run them in the order that you have dependencies (unless you have two way dependencies - I am not even sure how that would work!) so you effectively generate them offline then when it comes to deployment run the scripts (so you move the script generation to the CI step and the CD step becomes just to run the scripts rather than compare and then run scripts)

ed

Comment: interesting idea to create scripts the issue here is that we are doing CI so creating the scripts and running them might take longer then actually just publishing.

Comment: take into account that we are deploying precompiled dacpacs using SqlPackage.exe

Comment: I'm not sure it fits every scenario and I guess it might not help you here sorry

Comment: You could deploy without the Transactional checking, let the script error, then re-deploy. It's a _horrible_ solution, but it does seem to work to push objects with dependencies and then "fix" everything later.

Answer (score 0):

When you add dacpac as a database reference, you can mark it to ignore errors. It might be solution for your case.